# Deleting all table rows in a section

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios, uitableview, nsindexpath

For my iPad project I need to be able to reload table rows.
This is how it should works, depend on some "id" selected from a popupview, i need to be able to reload table rows, table rows are dynamics and has a UITextField in it. I tried to use [self.tableView reload] but for some reason it does not update the rows correctly. Something like UITextField placeholder owned by previous "id" does not change. What I have in mind is to remove all cells in that specific section and reload the table with the new "id". When i do this i got this exception:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (3) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (3), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 3 deleted).'

The project code:

```
- (void)selectedArchiefID:(NSString *) value {
   [self.popOverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];

   // collects all available document indexfields
   int rowCount = [indexDefinities count];
   NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

   for (int curIndex=0; curIndex < rowCount; curIndex++) {
       [indexPaths addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:curIndex inSection:0]];
   }

   // deletes rows
   if ([indexPaths count] > 0) {
      [self.tableView beginUpdates];
      [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
      //[self.tableView deleteSections:0 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        [self.tableView endUpdates]; //crashes here
   }

   [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Any idea what i did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to change the data of the datasource of the tableview.

You can't just change the tableview layout.

If you want to remove a section, you have to remove this section from the datasource first. 
You could do this the easy way, by removing the section in a NSMutableArray (which is your datasource).

Or you could write a big if then else monster that figures out how much sections (and rows) to return in `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`.

Doesn't matter how you do it, but you have to remove the data before you update the tableview.

---

One more thing, having both `[self.tableView beginUpdates]; /*...*/ [self.tableView endUpdates];` and `[self.tableView reloadData];` in one method is usually useless. THe latter would kill the animation effect you get from the first one.

Comment: i also tried to remove the entire section using: [self.tableView deleteSections:0 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone]; but it does not work. is this what you mean by removing the data?

Comment: nope. you are just removing the section from the tableview. And after this the tableview asks your datasource for the new datalayout, which is basically still exactly like the old layout. you have to update the values you return in `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`.

Comment: okay... now i get it. I'm now able to get the right number of rows for each "id" i've selected. The problem is that the textfield's placeholder text inside the row still contains the text from previous row. in have putted source code on how i do put the textfield inside row here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883664/ipad-sdk-getting-setting-uitextfield-value-in-a-table-cell